# How to prepare for IN clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT category_id as id FROM categories__shops WHERE category_id IN (:id) AND shop_id = 2 ORDER BY manual_sort_index", [
            "id" => $superParentsIds
        ])->fetchAll();
```

For some reason it fetches only the first id from the superParentIds. If I use it this way:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT category_id as id FROM categories__shops WHERE category_id IN ($superParentsIds) AND shop_id = 2 ORDER BY manual_sort_index")->fetchAll();
```

It works properly and returns mutliple results. How should I prepare the `$superParentsIds` ?

**EDIT**:
`$superParentsIds` is `(10006,10007,10009,10008,11294,10010,10011,10050)`

Comment: If `$superParentsIds` is a comma-separated string, you need to use `FIND_IN_SET()`, not `IN()`

Comment: Tried but `FIND_IN_SET` seems like not supported. Is it possible ? Using MySQL

Comment: please show the new query maybe a typo

Comment: Found the problem. Didn't need to `implode` the array.

Comment: @Progman this is PDO, not mysqli.